# Creating animated in Splash in Maui (setting MainActivity OnCreate and other things)?

Tags: maui, android-splashscreen

This question started from an Android article I tried to implement in Maui. Mostly it was about implementing custom Android resource XML files but I got stuck in implementing things on `OnCreate`. Hence that's where this started, but then escalated other potential solutions.

Then @user2153142 chimed in with Xamarin sample that unlocked the issue. Hence that's that accepted answer and this question is revised a bit to show it. Like how it started, how it went.

**So the old question was like this:**

I was following tutorial at https://www.droidcon.com/2022/10/04/splash-screen-in-android/ to set up animated Android Splash Screen in Maui.

But there is a "Step 5" I do not know how to set up the actual animation. In the code it is described as

```
class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        startActivity(Intent(this@SplashScreenActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
}
```

I was thinking it could be something like

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class SplashScreenActivity: MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //So, passing this intent doesn't work here at all now. Argh! How should this be done?
        StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(this.SplashScreen, typeof(MainActivity)));
        Finish();
    }
}
```

in .NET Maui, but I fail to realize how to create the intent so I could pass `MainActivity` and whatever is that `SplashScreenActivity` in this as parameters here. That activity is the default activity, basically.

I learned elsewhere that `SplashScreenActivity` should be set as `MainLauncher = true` and in .NET Maui it automatically generated a section to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <!--
      This activity is generated by SplasScreenActivity,
      the contents may differ as they depend on that activity
      definition. This can be verified by looking at
    \obj\Debug\net7.0-android\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml
    -->
    <!--
    <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    -->

  </application>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
</manifest>
```

It appears one can't just set `<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/MainTheme</item>` in `styles.xml` either to declare the main theme as it one cannot set `Parent="Theme.SplashScreen"` in the styles describing the Splash theme (probably the values could be copied from somewhere?).

Further in that same tutorial there is a more advanced way of setting up the activity. It might be better, from the tutorial

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Enable support for Splash Screen API for
        // proper Android 12+ support
        installSplashScreen()
        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

but there doesn't seem to be `InstallSplashScreen` in .NET Maui. Also I would not know how to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in .NET (there is `SetContentView` function, however).

There are other tutorials too that might allow one to bypass some of these issues. One is at https://www.truiton.com/2022/10/implementing-the-splash-activity-in-android-the-right-way/, but it appears there'll be similar issues with `AppCompatActivity` functions.

**But it got complicated.** The provided answer was close to the price,  and Maui builds on Android (and old) Xamarin bits. Or that what I believe it does.

Here are a few modifications I did:

In `.csproj` there is

```xml
 <ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

 <MauiIcon Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) != true" Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) != true" Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

(Maybe they all should be conditionals, but this is how it is now and it works.)

The resource are laid out like this:
[image]

`AndroidManifest.xml` is defined like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
</manifest>
```

It's important to target a SDK over 31, I think.

`styles.xml` is defined like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/appicon_foreground</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/animated_face</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Maui.SplashTheme">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Here `AppTheme` is the main theme, `AppTheme.Starting` is the "splash theme". In my mind this means chaining these actions together. Notice that unlike in the comments in the answer, I think this is what it set in `MainActivity.cs` and it seems to work. Setting the `AppTheme` does not, there's just the application background showing. That probably is because there isn't the `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon` isn't set there. I have not tried if it could, maybe. Also it doesn't have the `android:` prefix, maybe works with it too. Or all others without also.

Nothing remarkable in `colors.xml`, I think.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ffff1c</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00c3ff</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#3b3d3b</color>
</resources>
```

That file `animated_face.xml" was copied from https://yggr.medium.com/exploring-android-12-splash-screen-21f88cc8e8f8 and modified so it blinks (I needed to find something I can understand and test with)

```xml
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
  <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
    <vector
        android:name="vector"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24">
      <path
          android:name="path"
          android:pathData="M 9 11.75 C 8.31 11.75 7.75 12.31 7.75 13 C 7.75 13.69 8.31 14.25 9 14.25 C 9.69 14.25 10.25 13.69 10.25 13 C 10.25 12.31 9.69 11.75 9 11.75 Z M 15 11.75 C 14.31 11.75 13.75 12.31 13.75 13 C 13.75 13.69 14.31 14.25 15 14.25 C 15.69 14.25 16.25 13.69 16.25 13 C 16.25 12.31 15.69 11.75 15 11.75 Z M 12 2 C 6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12 C 2 17.52 6.48 22 12 22 C 17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12 C 22 6.48 17.52 2 12 2 Z M 12 20 C 7.59 20 4 16.41 4 12 C 4 11.71 4.02 11.42 4.05 11.14 C 6.41 10.09 8.28 8.16 9.26 5.77 C 11.07 8.33 14.05 10 17.42 10 C 18.2 10 18.95 9.91 19.67 9.74 C 19.88 10.45 20 11.21 20 12 C 20 16.41 16.41 20 12 20 Z"
          android:fillColor="#000"
          android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    </vector>
  </aapt:attr>
  <target android:name="path">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
      <objectAnimator
          android:propertyName="fillColor"
          android:duration="2000"
          android:valueFrom="#bb86fc"
          android:valueTo="#ffffff"
          android:valueType="colorType"
          android:repeatCount="-1"
          android:repeatMode="reverse"
          android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
    </aapt:attr>
  </target>
</animated-vector>
```

and finally `MainActivity.cs` looks like this

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;


namespace SomeApp;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/AppTheme.Starting", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity: MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen.SplashScreen.InstallSplashScreen(this);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Include this if using the Splash Screen API - rotate to Landscape on a device with a notch to see why - with this code commented.
        if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.P)
        {
            Window.Attributes.LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode.Default;
        }

        // If you want to get a good look at the icon to check it. Don't forget remove from production code
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

So, almost like the application. When I run this, the face is blinking when the app is loading (also while it's stopped in the debugger is there's a breakpoint there) and then switches over to the application screen.

I don't know how `AndroidManifest.xml` should look like so it's correct, but one can check it at `\obj\Debug\net7.0-android\AndroidManifest.xml`. I'll include this bit information here as it's something I learned while doing this.

I think this was it. The actual code is at https://github.com/gmck/XamarinBasicSplashScreen and here with slight Maui related modifications to make it work.

If you know this can be improved or perfected, please do chime in. There seem to be something related e.g. at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Veksi

To get an understanding of how a splash screen should be implemented in Xamarin.Android you can use the following example https://github.com/gmck/XamarinBasicSplashScreen.

One thing you can't do with Android 12 and above is use the two activity technique that you refer to above. There is only one additional line of code that is added to the standard blank app template, the rest is done via an additional theme. Works for Android 13 down to Android 5.0

I can't help you with Maui as I've never used it, but if you read the thread https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/7239 you will see how this helped out developer9969 with his xamarin.forms app, therefore I'm assuming you could do something similar with Maui.

For more detailed Android info refer to https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen.

I could also convert it from xamarin.android to a net7.0-android app if you would find that more helpful.

Comment: I'll try to check these later today, thanks! I think I am partially confused a to what should work _in Android_ alone. I don't think Maui changes much from Xamarin. This question escalated a bit from where I started to solve thing to have an animated logo on light and dark and the non-animated working too.

Comment: I got it to work. Let I accept this "tomorrow" (it's midnight here). I fix the heading, fix the question a bit and write a few notes. F.e.x. I didn't use "SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main)", I set "Activity(Theme = "@style/AppTheme.Starting"," and such. I tried only with API 33 Android 13 emulator and got a blinking vector drawable using `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon`. :)

Comment: You don't want AppTheme.Starting in the Activity attribute. The original theme is deliberately removed from the Activity attribute. The swapping of themes is done automatically by <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item> or whatever you call your theme name.

Comment: I suppose the issue is that I don't know how to set the default theme without setting it in the activity. If I understand correctly, the Maui tooling picks the attribute and merges it with `AndroidManifest.xml` (I might be wrong). Probably it should be possible in the resources, but I'd need to do some more research on it.

Answer (score 1):

I've got no real clue about Maui as I never used it. I just had a quick look at a standard Maui app, build a standard app and checked the generated manifest in the obj folder. The manifest file inputs the theme as android:theme="@style/Maui.SplashTheme", so that would be what you would normally use. However, you probably don't want that so then continue searching the obj folder. The path where I found styles.xml was C:\ProjectsVS2022Preview\MauiApp1\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\lp\154\jl\res\values\styles.xml

Open that file in VS and reformat the text to make it easier to read. There appears to be two styles Maui.MainTheme and Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar. Which one you choose depends on your android app type. Where my app had @style/AppTheme change postSplashScreenTheme to one of those Maui theme names and then delete any theme in the Activity attribute.

Remember this is only an Android solution - not going to work for the other platforms.

Comment: I'm on .NET 7.0, but maybe doesn't matter. If I do as you describe, first it shows the app icon, not the animation. Then after a while `Android.Views.InflateException` is raised in `OnCreate`. If I do like I described in the post on API 33 there's animation and on API 28 an icon and after the splash the normal application view. I don't know if this still close enough "resource only splash read" or if could be optimized still, but seem to be working solution. Too bad I don't (yet) know enough about Android nor Maui to tell what could be done here.

Comment: @Veksi, I've just converted the XamarinBasicSplashScreen to Net7, so you may be able to use that to help with converting it to Maui .Net7. I'm writing the docs so will publish in tomorrow morning. Will let you know here when I'm done.

Comment: I look forward to it! I just checked that solution I use with https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#splash-screen-resources as the icon and it doesn't seem to work. The ion just seem to come to the screen, slightly moving towards centre from bottom left corner. I don't know if it's my code, emulator or something else (stutter in computer?). The plot thickens.

Comment: @Veksi, The .Net7 version is now available. I'm a bit confused by some of your comments.  There is no animation of the icon because the icon is the standard Maui icon. If you want an animation, you will need a new icon and then provide the code to animate it - see the docs about their specification etc. and the code required. The app icon should be centred on the screen with a background colour of whatever you choose for windowSplashScreenBackground. If done correctly in Maui the splash screen should look no different to what it does in this test app. What device and version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

@Veksi
I've reread your original post and have only now realised that you had already seen my XamarinBasicSplashScreen app. I can see in your original post where there is style that contains errors.

name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/animated_face
The **android:** is wrong if you are using androidx.core.splashscreen

if you check my style it is

```
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
```

when using XamarinSplashScreenBasic

```
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/appicon_foreground</item>
```

and now in xamarinSplashScreenBasicNet7

Basically anytime you see android: something on the left side that is the framework therefore Android 12+ only. So to work with devices less than 12 we need androidX.

Your example is a case of mixing up the android framework way rather than using the syntax of androidx.core.splashscreen. So that was never going to work.

As Xamarin users using Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen we must use androidX syntax.

The SomeApp namespace example is pretty much right, except it doesn't need the theme in the Activity Attribute as it should already be in the manifest. Looks like it came from my app when you check the comments.

If you do want to do animation of the icon, you then will need to follow the explorer Android 12 link.

I'd suggest getting XamarinSplashScreenBasicNet7 to work in a Maui .Net7 app just as a basic Android 12 splash screen before attempting to get animation working.

***but there doesn't seem to be InstallSplashScreen in .NET Maui.***
Well there is in Xamarin but the C# syntax is completely different

```
AndroidX.Core.SplashScreen.SplashScreen.InstallSplashScreen(this);
```

When you do get it right with Maui can you please post a link?

Comment: Hi! I just noticed this. I think I can try in a few weeks. I am thinking trying to add a sound effect too. This worked for me, but when I try add sound, probably I have the energy to try to make this as a minimal Maui app too.